# How to reduce one column and increase other one in CSS?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am trying to set `width:13%` of `Date` column. But it doesn't work in my way. Where is the problem? and can't reduce `width` of `subject` column. Thanks in advance.

Check **[FIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/p5d76ju4/)**

```html
<div style="width:70%;float:left;">
   <div>
      <table style="width:100%;" class="TicketsDashboard">
         <tbody>
            <tr>
               <td style="width:13%"><b>Date</b></td>
               <td ><b>Type</b></td>
               <td ><b>Subject</b></td>
               <td ><b>Responsible</b></td>
               <td ><b>Action</b></td>
            </tr>
            <tr style="cursor:pointer;" onclick="openDetailDiv('PROT-155',124)">
               <td>2019-07-21 12:52:08</td>
               <td>Recommendation</td>
               <td>First Subject going on perfectly edited</td>
               <td>perfect</td>
               <td class="editButtonMain">Edit</td>
            </tr>
            <tr style="cursor:pointer;" onclick="openDetailDiv('PROT-155',125)">
               <td>2019-07-21 12:53:26</td>
               <td>Decision</td>
               <td>lklk kdj djjdjdjdjdjdjdjdjdjdjdjdjdjdjjdjdjdjdjdjdjdjdjdjdjdjdjdjdjdjdjdjdjdjdjdjdjdjdjdjdjdjdjdjdjdjdjdj</td>
               <td>bangldesh</td>
               <td class="editButtonMain">Edit</td>
            </tr>
         </tbody>
      </table>
   </div>
   <br>
   <div id="ticketButtons"><input type="button" class="Btn" onclick="openDiag({function: &quot;item&quot;, id: 155, dialogTitle: this.value})" value="Add Protocol Item"></div>
</div>
<div style="width:30%;float:left">
   <table style="width:100%;" class="lightborder" id="headTable">
      <tbody>
         <tr id="slaTr">
            <td width="100" valign="top">SLA:</td>
            <td>
               <div id="effortDiv" style="width:50%;float:left;text-align:center;padding-bottom:10px;display:none"></div>
               <div id="timeDiv" style="text-align:center;padding-bottom:10px;display:none"></div>
            </td>
         </tr>
         <tr>
            <td width="100">Status:</td>
            <td id="statusTd">Suggestion</td>
         </tr>
         <tr>
            <td>Protocol Number:</td>
            <td id="breadCrumb">PROT-155</td>
         </tr>
         <tr>
            <td>Subject:</td>
            <td id="protsubject">Chonchol -- test</td>
         </tr>
         <tr>
            <td>Start Date:</td>
            <td id="protstartdate">0000-00-00 00:00:00</td>
         </tr>
         <tr>
            <td>End Date:</td>
            <td id="protenddate">0000-00-00 00:00:00</td>
         </tr>
         <tr>
            <td>Keeper:</td>
            <td id="protkeeper">ewrwer</td>
         </tr>
      </tbody>
   </table>
</div>
```

Comment: Why are you using a percent value? Why not using em to specify the size of chars are really needed? Let the table decide how much it is. To avoid the date to be broken into several lines, you could specify that date columns to `style="white-space: no-wrap;"`. Better use classes than repeating inline styles.

Answer (score 1):

your subject column is going out because u didn't used space in this code `<td>lklk kdj djjdjdjdjdjdjdjdjdjdjdjdjdjdjjdjdjdjdjdjdjdjdjdjdjdjdjdjdjdjdjdjdjdjdjdjdjdjdjdjdjdjdjdjdjdjdjdj</td>` if you want to be stop exceeding you can give space like this `<td>lklk kdj djjdjdjdjdjd jdjdjdjdjdjdjdj djjdjdjdjdjdjdj djdjdjdjdjdjdjdjdjdjdjdj djdjdjdjdjdjdjdjdjdjdjdjdjdjdj</td>`
What actually you wanted to get let us know clearly.

Answer (score 0):

1. To increase the width of td 
   instead of  `<td style="width:13%">` give `<td style="padding-left:13%">`
2. To avoid the overflow
   add

   `<style>
    table { table-layout:fixed; }
    table td {word-wrap:break-word;}
   </style>`

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

the reason of it, you should set the same style for the given column in every rows, or add a thead section in which you set it once of the column.